# What can be a replacement for this brand of sink faucet?

Tags: bathroom, sink, bathroom-fixtures

I need to get a replacement handle for one of the sinks in the bathroom which has a broken handle.  Handle is acrylic and has a square stem.  I can't seem to find the name of the brand anywhere on the faucet-either the back or the front or on the pipes.  It seems like an 80s faucet but I may be wrong. I don't wish to replace the entire faucet if it can be avoided.  Incase this kind of handle is no longer available, would a spigot wheel fit?  I do not care how it looks, just need a functional faucet.

Any help/tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look under the spout (with a mirror or cell phone camera) - I'd guess Delta, but the picture with the handle on is a bit small to show detail.

Comment: Thanks Ecnerwal.  I looked under the spout as you suggested but there is no brand name.  I couldn't find it anywhere on the faucet or under the sink.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell for sure but it looks like an old Delta or Kohler. However, if you remove that acrylic knob and take it into your local plumbing or home store I think there's a good chance you'll find a replacement.
You can also try calling the Kohler or Delta customer service line. They are very good at identifying their discontinued products by looking at a picture. Simply send the ones you posted here.

Comment: yeah, plumbing store is definately the right answer here,or a building recycler if you want an exact match.

Comment: Thanks so much HoneyDo and Jasen!  I have written to Delta and could not get the details on Kohler portal.  I will also stop by the plumbing store to see if I can get one.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't care about looks, any knob that fits will do just fine.

Comment: @Pam G - You can call Kohler CS at 1 800 456-4537 or go to their website and click on "Identify My Product".